# How can I build an expression that compiles to a Func<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, expression, expression-trees

Suppose I have a static method that returns T such as:

```
T myT = MyClass.Create(type); // type is System.Type
```

I then want to be able to build and compile an expression so that I can have a `Func<T>` but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I can build it for a `Constant` doing:

```
Func<T> result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(Expression.Constant(string.Empty)).Compile()
```

but for `MyClass.Create(type)` I am stuck.

```
Func<T> result = ....?
```

Comment: Expression.Call? What have you tried?

Comment: Brilliant that did the trick :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the tip from `usr` I managed to do it using `Expression.Call` so given:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string GetTime() 
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff");
    }

    public static string GetName(Type type)
    {
        return type.Name;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
// Calls static method GetTime with no args
var mCallGetTime = Expression.Call(typeof(MyClass), "GetTime", null);
Func<string> resultNoArg = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(mCallGetTime).Compile();

// The input param for GetName which is of type Type
var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type));

// Calls static method GetName passing in the param
var mCallGetName = Expression.Call(typeof(MyClass), "GetName", null, paramExp);
Func<Type, string> resultWithArg = Expression.Lambda<Func<Type, string>>(mCallGetName, paramExp).Compile();

// You can then call them like so... Print() just prints the string
resultNoArg().Print();
resultWithArg(typeof(string)).Print();
resultWithArg(typeof(int)).Print();
```

Alternatively, Instead of:

```
var mCallGetTime = Expression.Call(typeof(MyClass), "GetTime", null);
```

We could compose the `Expression.Call` using:

```
// Get the method info for GetTime (note the Type[0] signifying no args taken by GetTime);
var methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("GetTime", new Type[0]);
var mCallGetTime = Expression.Call(methodInfo);
```

Likewise for `GetName`:

```
// Get the method info for GetName (note the new[] {typeof(Type)} signifying the arg taken by GetName
var getNameMethodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("GetName", new[] { typeof(Type)});
var mCallGetName = Expression.Call(getNameMethodInfo, paramExp);
```

Comment: if you compile an expression straight away, then most of the time you dont need it, what is wrong with your first line?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to your answer is to create a fully generic method that will construct a `Func<T>` for any generic, static method in any type.

```
public Func<T> BuildGenericStaticFunc<T>()
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(
        Expression
            .Call(
                type.GetMethod("Create", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .MakeGenericMethod(type),
                Expression.Constant(type)
                ))
            .Compile();
}

var result = BuildGenericStaticFunc<MyClass>();
```